# Java Sockets - receiving blank buffer

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I'm getting a strange results of reading the `InputStream` of `Socket`.
When I'm sending data from my program I'm getting a valid result ONCE.
When I'm doing it from separate program I get valid data but the server keeps on reading that same message, even if I don't send anything, just connect to a socket I get empty array.

```
in = socket.getInputStream();
out = socket.getOutputStream();
dIn = new DataInputStream(in);

while(this.isAlive()) {
        try {
            dIn.read(buffer);

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            for(int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
                builder.append(buffer[i]).append(" ");
            }

            builder.append("\n");

            System.out.println(builder.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Output (just connecting to socket):

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Your code contains at least one significant but (that can cause all kind of trouble), but you should definitely read [mcve] and enhance your question. For example: where is that *buffer* array coming from?

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the javadoc for [read()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D)):

> Returns:
>
> the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or -1 if there is no more data because the end of the stream has been reached.

Your code is simply **not** at all checking that result. You **assume** that all bytes were read, and that simply doesn't work (sometimes).

In other words: always always always, when you call some `read()` method that returns such a value, your code **absolutely** must check the result to ensure that (the expected) data was actually received by reading.

Most likely, this is part of your problem. But to be really sure, you will need to enhance your question with more information.

Comment: thanks, it works now, I thought it blocks the thread and waits until there are some bytes to read so in this case it wouldnt print out empty data.